# Unable to open gallery pick an image and place it in the ImageView

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview, gallery

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    ImageView mImageview;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        mImageview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgView);

        view.findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    requestPermissions(
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            2000);
                }
                else {
                    startGallery();
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private void startGallery() {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        cameraIntent.setType("image/*");
        if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1000 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        }
        Uri returnUri;
        returnUri = data.getData();

        Glide.with(this)
                .load(returnUri)
                .override(1280, 1280)
                .centerCrop()
                .crossFade()
                .into(mImageview);
    }
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
}
```

I tried using the glide dependency and **I am working in fragments not activity** this code doesn't give anything in the output. 
**Even the gallery isn't opening**
Can someone tell what have i left ?
Looking forward to a prompt reply.